# How to add icon file in the cab file of mobile application?

Tags: c#, windows-mobile, compact-framework, icons, cab

I am developing smart device application in C#. When I deploy my application on emulator it shows the default name for the exe of my application & there is no icon associated with it. Now I have added an icon to the exe of my application by right clicking on the project & selecting the properties from the solution explorer in visual studio. Then I selected the application tab & given the path of the icon(.ico file)by selecting the radio button Icon & Manifest. Now when I run my application on the emulator it shows icon on the exe file with default name. I have added the Smart Device Cab Project to my application to create the cab file. My application runs fine after installing the cab file. My question is that is there any need to add the icon(.ico file) to the cab? If it is needed then where should I add that icon file(.ico file) to the cab project so that my application shows the icon on the exe ? Or there is no need to add the icon file(.ico file to the cab project ? Can you please provide me any suggestions or link through which I can resolve the above issue ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The icon is an embedded resource in your EXE, so there is no need to deploy it separately.  Bear in mind that WinMo caches icons for the Start menu, so if you deployed or installed the app without an icon, to get it to show the new icon in the Start menu you'll have to soft-reset the device.